# One widget focused StreamBuilder refresh whole screen

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have this widget.

```
class YourStreamBuilder extends StatefulWidget {
  final String postId;
  const YourStreamBuilder({Key? key, required this.postId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<YourStreamBuilder> createState() => _YourStreamBuilderState();
}

class _YourStreamBuilderState extends State<YourStreamBuilder> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .doc(widget.postId)
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const SizedBox();
        }

        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
          );
        }

        int likesCount = snapshot.data!['likes'].length;

        bool isLiked = false;

        //check user liked or not

        isLiked = (snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>)['likes']
            .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid);

        return Column(
          children: [
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                await StatusScreenBackend()
                    .addorRemoveLike(widget.postId, isLiked);
              },
              child: isLiked
                  ? SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/icons/filling.svg',
                      key: ValueKey<bool>(isLiked),
                      semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo',
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 35,
                    )
                  : SvgPicture.asset(
                      'assets/icons/like_icon.svg',
                      key: ValueKey<bool>(isLiked),
                      semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo',
                      color: Colors.white,
                      height: 35,
                    ),
            ),

            // SvgToggleWidget(postId: postId, isLiked: isLiked),
            CustomText(
              size: 16,
              text: likesCount.toString(),
              textColor: Colors.white,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I call it from HomeScreen, like this (in column)

`YourStreamBuilder(postId: firstsnapshot.docs[index].data()['postId']),` like this.

---

It works properly; however, when touched, it refreshes the entire page. I want it to refresh only that specific item (Like button color) and the count of likes. On my home screen, there are other FutureBuilders and Stream Builders.

Comment: `stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('posts')
          .doc(widget.postId)
          .snapshots(),` DO NOT build the Stream in the stream: parameter of the StreamBuilder.

Comment: It's under FirestoreQueryBuilder. So, Can't remove it.  Can solve this problem using ValueListenableBuilder?

Comment: Add a field to your widget state that holds the stream, then initialize that field in `initState`.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the specific widget in a RepaintBoundary(). This prevents other parts of the widget tree to re-render.

But please keep in mind that instantiating the stream directly in the StreamBuilder is not a good practice. This can cause a lot of unnecessary reads on you firestore db. Instantiate the stream only once somewhere in your app and just reference it in the StreamBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign a variable the value of your stream... something like this:

```
// Declare a variable.
late final Future _future;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _future = _getCollection(); // Assign your Future to it. 
}

// This is your actual Future. Name it whatever you want. 
Future _getCollection() => FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('posts')
    .doc(widget.postId)
    .snapshots();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
      stream: _future,
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
      ... // Rest of the code
```